# Format Specifier for Tall letter output in hexadecimal

Tags: c

When I want to print a hexadecimal value of an integer using printf in C, I use the following statement : `printf ("\n X = 0x%x \n",x);` Here I assume the following declaration : `int x = -1`

Now this prints `Oxffffffff`. I would like to see the output as 0xFFFFFFFF (all Tall Letters). Which format specifier will help me achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf ("\n X = 0x%X \n",x);`

Comment: Thanks and what does "0x%1$X" do ?